# How do I override example for specific properties in components in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

Here's the minimal working [example](https://editor.swagger.io/):

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - customName
      properties:
        genericName:
          type: string
          example: Alex
        customName:
          type: string
          example: Ivanov
```

I would like to use a component `Pet` for the spec above yet I would like to be able to override an example for `customName` (the reason is it's like a URL in my real example and I'd like it be specific and it's based on the current resource but the component itself is shared among multiple resources if that makes sense).

I tried #1:

```
...
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
              example:
                customName: IvanovOverride
components:
...
```

```
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
              example:
                properties:
                  customName: IvanovOverride
```

and #3:

```
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  - properties:
                      customName: 
                        example: IvanovOverride
```

but they all didn't work on [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) (the doc always showed "Ivanov" as an example).

Answer (score 1):

If you use OpenAPI 3.1, and you have the necessary tooling supporting it, you can use the `$dynamicAnchor` and `$dynamicRef` for solving the problem.

Example:

```yaml
openapi: "3.1.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PetWithFirstExampleName"
components:
  schemas:
    PetWithFirstExampleName:
      properties:
        customName:
          example: firstExampleName
      $dynamicAnchor: customNameExample
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    Pet:
      type: object
      $dynamicRef: customNameExample
      required:
        - customName
      properties:
        genericName:
          type: string
          example: Alex
        customName:
          type: string
          # example is provided by the schema referenced by $dynamicRef
```

Note: this is a quite new feature of json schema and OpenAPI, so you can easily run into problems with the implementations.

Note 2: yours is an approximately similar usecase as [this one](https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/blob/master/tests/draft2020-12/dynamicRef.json#L248) in the official json schema test suite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm afraid I'm using v3.0.0 atm.